# Jenkins run as service on Ubuntu - headfull instad of headless

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

this is my first question ever here, so please forgive me, if it's not as informative (the description of the problem) as it could be.

I'm getting a little desperate.

I'm trying to run Selenium tests on Ubuntu using Jenkins. And I did manage to achieve it when starting Jenkins as a service (using jenkins.war), which is awesome. There were several errors during execution before I switched to "service mode".

But tests run in headless mode, which I found out is default mode for Jenkins as service on Linux.
And I really need them to be visible while executing.

And I have no idea how to achieve this. I tried with Xvfb plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/xvfb/), but (maybe I do something wrong?) tests are still not displayed when running. I'm not even sure if this plugin allows them to be visible.

I know, that for Windows there is checkbox "Allow service to interact with Desktop", is there maybe something similar for Linux?

Thank you in advance for any feedback.